# ERROR Response {_body: "JSONP injected script did not invoke callback.", status: 200, ok: true, statusText: "Ok", headers: Headers, …}

Tags: angular, rest, http-get, angular-services

In my HTML I have a button which triggers a request to an API which is supposed to request a list of users, preferably using Json.
//html

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="form-area">  
        <form #userform="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onClick(userform)" >
        <br style="clear:both">
                    <h3 style="margin-bottom: 25px; text-align: center;">Login Form</h3>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Username" required [(ngModel)]="log.username" >

                    </div>


                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="Password" class="form-control" id="pwd" name="password" placeholder="Password" required [(ngModel)]="log.password">
                    </div>



        <button type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" [disabled]="userform.invalid">Login</button>
        </form>
    </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div><button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" (click)="test()">Test</button></div>
</div>
```

//ts file

this is the ts file see the test() function

```
test(){
    this.authenticate.testing().subscribe(res=> {
    this.data=res.json();
    console.log(this.data);
    })
  }
```

is the format is right or wrong

// service file

```
testing(){

       let params = new URLSearchParams(); 
         params.set('key', 'null');  
    params.set('username', 'sundhar@sample.net');  
    params.set('password', 'welcome');  
    params.set('format', 'json'); 
return this.jsonp.get('http://localhost:9000/EzeeShipping_Java/users' , {search: params }).map(response => response.json()); 
    }
```

it shows the error like

ERROR Response {_body: "JSONP injected script did not invoke callback.", status: 200, ok: true, statusText: "Ok", headers: Headers, …}

i need to get the json and want to display the user list in screen kindly help me to get the json file

Comment: this should not have the angularjs tag

Comment: Cant understand

Comment: don't worry, someone already fixed it :)

Comment: Can you plz send me the fixed one

Comment: I meant they fixed the wrong tag you had in your post (not related to an answer)